# detecting the network level logging in esxi level logs

Tags: vmware

I have downloaded the esxi level logs. I want to check network errors in those logs. Can anyone please help me to know how can we detect the network level logging in esxi level logs?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also if anyone could help me to know if we can see CRC errors in the esxi level logs, if any?